# what does "make this/that/ fly" mean?

Tags: idioms

> You really think you're gonna be able to *make that fly*?

I heard this phrase in the movie *Crash* (I think).  I've googled it but came up with  nothing.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. There are many different possible meanings, as there are many literal and metaphorical uses of *[fly](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fly)*; can you at least provide us with the complete quotation, in context? Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may be of interest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a metaphor from the invention of powered aircraft.  During the industrial revolution life was changing quickly.  Many people didn't understand the new fangled gadgets.  Others thought they did and wanted in on making new inventions.

Many crazy ideas got pitched on newsreels but few ever left the ground.
One thing everyone picked up on though was that an aircraft that has never flown is unproven.  Once it took to the air and landed safely people gained a lot of respect for the design and its inventors.

Eventually "make that fly" or "get it off the ground" became expressions that applied to more than aircraft.  So the question is a metaphor.  It's asking if the idea will ever be proven to be viable.

Comment: You would very rarely see the phrase written anywhere, other than in film dialogue, or in a quotation of fairly casual speech. However "get off the ground" is more likely to be used as metaphor by writers.

Comment: @Cargill—But you're forgetting about "business speak", or the jargon people love to use to make themselves sound good (supposedly). "We can't make this project fly unless we're all on the same page, right?"

Comment: No - I wasn't discounting business-speak (or government-speak) at all ... the phrase is probably used a lot, however my small point is, it wouldn't be written too often, unless the author is quoting (or paraphrasing) someone (say in an interview in a business magazine or government newsletter, etc).

Comment: @Cargill Are you simply trying to indicate that the expression isn't a formal one?

Comment: No, not really; there are hundreds of idiomatic and informal expressions that have made it into written form, so being in print isn't necessarily a distinguishing characteristic of formality.